# Custom metrics using Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Is it possible to set a custom metrics for Memory utilization for the environment in Elastic Beanstalk. I know the way of giving commands to EB environment through .ebextensions folder. But could not find it for Custom metrics.

Answer (score 0):

Custom metrics such as memory utilization are only available on an instance's OS level (rather than an EB environment level), and for which you'll need to install the AWS CloudWatch agent on your instance(s). If you are using a recent Amazon Linux AMI it should already be installed. You will also need to make sure the instances in your environment have roles with the correct permissions to write to CloudWatch

[Installation docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/Install-CloudWatch-Agent.html)

Once this is set up and the instances in your environment are putting out the memory usage data, you should then be able to accumulate them in CloudWatch in a graph or text widget, or just use the Metrics section in the CloudWatch side menu.